# How to get the Doctype Declaration in Xerces-C when using SAX2?

Tags: c++, xml, xerces

I am using SAX2 from Xerces-C to read an XML document. However, I would like to check the Doctype declaration (if there is any) to make sure that the XML file is in the format I am expecting.

I have tried the unparsedEntityDecl and notationDecl methods from the [DTDHandler](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDTDHandler.html), and [EntityResolver](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classEntityResolver.html) seems to be more low-level than what I am looking for.

My motivation is for this is to be able to confirm that the input is of the format I am expecting so that I can differentiate between documents which produce no output and those that are entirely of the wrong format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [LexicalHandler](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classLexicalHandler.html) - startDTD will get you the Doctype.
However, it does not validate that the document actually follows that Doctype.
You need to enable validation in the reader with [setFeature](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classSAX2XMLReader.html#a597ea87071e1a0aa1288567e4bfd6d7) to do that.
( I've only used Java Xerces, but from the docs, it looks like the methods
  are basically the same. )

Comment: Thanks! This worked once I remembered/realised to "register" my Handler using the SAX2XMLReader::setLexicalHandler() method as well as just implementing it.