# How to get internal subset using SAX parser in XercesC?

Tags: xml, dtd, xerces-c

I would like to fetch the internal subset (the internal part of the DTD) from an XML file. `DOMDocumentType` has a `getInternalSubset()` method, but I'm using a SAX parser, not a DOM one. How could I access the internal subset using a SAX parser?

I'm using XercesC version 3.2.4.

Comment: clues? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822830/how-to-get-the-doctype-declaration-in-xerces-c-when-using-sax2